# For how many pairs of primes $(p, q)$ , is $p^2 + 2pq + 1$ also a prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This question was asked in
https://tessellate.cmi.ac.in/pastPapers/STEMS2023-Maths-CategoryA.pdf PART A Q8
here is my approach please help if you can [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol1wg.jpg)